# RegEx works everywhere except in Pentaho RegEx Evaluation Step

Tags: regex, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a couple of RegEx that work on the online regex websites but not in Pentaho. Could you please help?

Here's the string:

```
:6585d0f0ba88767ac3b590f719596d864d73e9c1:

harmonicbalance/src/harmonicbalance/HarmonicBalanceFlowModel.cpp
harmonicbalance/src/harmonicbalance/HbFlutterModel.cpp
:8302994b565553c83a048b8905ae597349d99627:

emp/src/emp/PhasePairSingleParticleReynoldsNumber.h
emp/src/emp/TomiyamaDragCoefficientMethod.cpp
:9da194f17ec08bb20ad1be8df68b78ca137ab18a:

combustion/src/combustion/ReactingSpeciesTransportBasedModel.cpp
combustion/src/complexchemistry/TurbulentFlameClosure.cpp
:6a59f0be1e347a65e525e58742bb304639ea9bc4:

meshing/src/meshing/SurfaceMeshManipulation.cpp
physics/src/discretization/FvIndirectRegionInterfaceManager.cpp
physics/src/discretization/FvIndirectRegionInterfaceManager.h
physics/src/discretization/FvRepresentation.cpp
physics/src/discretization/FvRepresentation.h
:64b7f6d36b11b6cd94c20cad53463b7deef8c85a:

resourceclient/src/resourceclient/ResourcePool.cpp
resourceclient/src/resourceclient/ResourcePool.h
resourceclient/src/resourceclient/RestClient.cpp
resourceclient/src/resourceclient/RestClient.h
resourceclient/src/resourceclient/test/ResourcePoolTest.cpp
```

I would like to capture two groups. First group will extract all commit SHA1 and the other group would extract file names.

Below are the expressions I tried:

```
(?:^:([A-Za-z0-9]+):|(?!^)\G)\n+([A-Za-z/.-]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/3IBkPz/1

```
^:(\w+):\s+((?:\s*(?!:)[^\s]+)+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/oIoDvM/1

Thoughts?

Comment: maybe the negative lookahead is not supported, note `(?!:)[^\s]+` could be changed by `[^\s:][^\s]*`

Comment: RegEx step gets stuck when I use this ^:(\w+):\s+((?:\s*[^\s:][^\s]*)+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK (as of PDI-8.0), the `Regex Evaluation` step does NOT support the regex '**g**' modifier, your regex pattern must cover all the text to be able to make a match.

For example: the following pattern will not match anything in *Regex Evaluation* step:

```
:([0-9a-f]+):\s+([^:]+)
```

but if I prepend `.*` to this pattern and pick "*Enable dotall mode*":

```
.*:([0-9a-f]+):\s+([^:]+)
```

it will match the last commit(sha1 + filenames). You can try move `.*` to the end of 
the original pattern which will get you the first commit. So if you want to retrieve 
the full list of commits(sha1 + filenames) with the **g** modifier, this step is 
probably not a solution for you.

As the fields are basically split by colons '**:**' and **new lines**, you can probably try the following approach:

1. Use **Split field to rows** step, Delimiter=':' and include rownum in output, this rownum can be used to filter rows where even number is sha1 and odd number is filenames
2. Use **Analytic Query** step to create a new field with LEAD = 1, so now you can get sha1 and filenames in the same row
3. Use **Calculator** and **Fileter** step to calculate the remainer of rownum/2 and keep only rows with the odd number of rownum
4. Use **Split fields to rows** again to split `filenames` to `filename` using "\n"(Delimiter is a Regular Expression). you might want to filter out the EMPTY filename, since the delimiter only support one `char`